# Why images set by android:src in xml remain stored in heap?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, fragment, heap-memory

I'm developing an application with various fragment activities with large images. I do not want to keep in memory this images across activities so i unbind the images with setImageBitmap(null). And retore restore images in onResume(). 
But why have to do the same with images set in xml if app have full reference? 
What is the best way to force all images in fragments to not keep in heap when leave activity and force recreate view when go back from other activity?
Why i set "setoffscreenPageLimit(1)" and images of three fragments stay always in heap? 3 is the min?
I'm using fragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With "setoffscreenPageLimit(1)" you are telling to the ViewPager to load in memory the next Fragment too. I mean, loads the Fragment of the left and the right of the current Fragment.

And don't try to set "setoffscreenPageLimit(0)", won't work.

-EDIT-

Also, you can set Images programmatically like this instead of setting them by xml.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this is for run the transtition smoothly.

Comment: @user2660673 if was useful to your problem please accept/vote the answer =D

Answer (score 0):

The best way is recycle your bitmaps when they are no longer use.

```
if(bitmap!=null)
   {
      bitmap.recycle();
      bitmap=null;

   }
```

Watch first 20 minuts of this official video if you want to make your day good - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk